# Best way to execute queries from multiple tables with sqlalchemy ORM?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Suppose we have an entity `MyEntity` with map a database table. To get all of the element in the mapped table I run the following code:

```
    with session_scope() as session:
        my_entities= session.query(MyEntity).all()
```

where `session_scope()` is nothing more than a function which provides a transactional scope around a series of operations.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from .config.db import database

Engine = create_engine(database)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=Engine)


@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Suppose now we have a second entity (let's call it `UnrelatedEntity`) mapping a second table without any kind of relationship with `MyEntity`. If, for some reason, I want all the records from both table within the same session scope, I write:

```
    with session_scope() as session:
        my_entities = session.query(MyEntity).all()
        unrelated_entities = session.query(UnrelatedEntity).all()
```

The question is simple: is this the best way to do it? And if it is not, what should a better alternative look like?

Thank you.

Comment: This is fine, there's no requirement that objects in a session should be related to each other.

Comment: The answer to the question can be "no: you are already doing it in the best way possible": if it's true I'll also accept that.